# C# LINQ: Extending Include to Convert it to list and Add OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq

I am planning on making an extension of the .Include() function.
Currently, something like this is what I've been using:

```
var data = _context.Examples
    .Include(example => examples.SubExamples)
    .FirstOrDefault();
if (data == null)
    return null;

data.SubExamples = data.SubExamples
    .OrderBy(subExamples => subExamples.CreatedOn)
    .ToList();

return data;
```

I need to order the "SubExample" by CreatedOn and convert it ToList() so the AutoMapper can map it without any issue. Since I'll be using the same method several times on different Entities, I'm planning on making an extension of the Include. But I'm having issue on how to re-assign the list.

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> IncludeOrderBy<TEntity, TProperty>(
    this IQueryable<TEntity> query,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> include,
    params Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>>[] orders)
{
    query.Include(include);

    // Need to assign to the Property as List() and Apply the OrderBy

    return query;
}
```

The question is how do I re-assign them back as List and add the Orders?

Comment: You do the ordering when you use it, or you have a class that holds your parent and child items and you assign them and return it. Will your code really get so much massively shorter and easier to use that all this is even worth it?

Comment: You should probably use `ProjectTo` and then no `Include` is needed.

Comment: Is the sort field name will always be "CreatedOn"?
I mean why you need to send the paramater "params Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>>[] orders"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you need params for orders but maybe this one can solve your problem

```
 public static IQueryable<T> IncludeOrderBy(this IQueryable<T> query, 
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
 {
     includes.ForEach(x => query = query.Include(x));

     if (orderBy != null)
     {
         query = orderBy(query);
     }
     return query;
 }
```

You can use it like that:

```
list.IncludeOrderBy(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.CreatedOn));
```

Comment: I made the order params, so that I can do multiple ordering or not. I'll be using the .OrderBy().ThenBy(). But that's not the point of the question, my question is how do I do the reassigning of the sorted data.

Comment: have you tried using it? 
list.IncludeOrderBy(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.CreatedOn).ThenBy(z => z.Creator));

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes I tested it, and it didn't give me the result I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return context.Examples
    .Include(example => examples.SubExamples)
    .FirstOrDefault()
    ?.SubExamples
    .OrderBy(subExamples => subExamples.CreatedOn)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Consider improving your answer. _[Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)_

Comment: @MickeyD unless it's an SQL query, in which case we will write the entire thing :D

Comment: This answer is not correct; it only returns the subitems when the OP actually wants the items and the sub items and he wants the sub items already ordered by some thing, and he wants it as an extension method. Answers should deliver on these things or clearly explain why they don't deliver them and encourage a different way of coding to solve the problem